# Forking existing pod on GitHub and using fork in Swift workspace - steps?

Tags: git, cocoapods, git-fork

I am missing something basic. I am comfortable with Cocoapods, podfiles, git but have just started both creating my own pods and properly forking and editing other pods (until now was happy to edit locally << i know: boo).

My issue is understanding steps needed after i fork Pod_A that was compiling in my workspace. My fork is Pod_B. I get the repo working on my own machine, both with SourceTree or git clone in Terminal. That is all good.

The part I am missing is the podspec or edits required to have me able to update the path to Pod_B within my podfile and carry on with the subsequent edits I want to formalize and integrate into my previously compiling workspace.

The pod install command after the fork is ready results in a "[!] No podspec found for `Pod_B` in *myRepoLocation* ..

Every example i find seems focused on a new project, or just getting the fork done. That is easy enough, but this last bit is just not quite right.

I have been searching for a while but to-date, have not found a seemingly proper example of this. Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use one of the Podfile pod options to point to your podspec. See https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#pod.

For example, `:path` to point to a local path or `:git` to specify a git location.

Comment: Thank you. I was missing the :git command.  Simple once you see it, many thanks! 

My standard update process after edits to my fork is to comment out the repo in my podfile, pod install to wipe it, then uncomment and pod install again.  This avoids the pod update cycle.  Is this the acceptable way generally?

Comment: `pod deintegrate` is a simpler way to wipe. Otherwise the rest depends on how versions are being managed. And of course, best practice is working with the original pod publisher to merge the fork :)

Comment: hey Paul, thanks kindly, but i think you missed the intention of my last comment referring to "my standard update process".  This was referring to grabbing the latest bits from just one pod.  Deintegrate is overkill in this workflow.

A note to others who sometimes will ram in quick edits to a local bits of a remote pod: cleaning the project is often vital for the project to see the edits, and especially breakpoints.